# Extract year complex query - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, where-clause, sql-in

I want to filter out my activities based on the multicombobox values with the last 4 Years. I am able to make a query to the database if I provide just one year.

```
SELECT * FROM public.events WHERE (EXTRACT(YEAR from start_date)) = 2019
```

However, I am not quite sure how can I give the query if I want to filter based on multiple years

```
SELECT * FROM public.events WHERE (EXTRACT(YEAR from start_date)) IN [2019, 2020]
```

is not working. How can I change my query?

Comment: You need parentheses for the [IN operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html#FUNCTIONS-COMPARISONS-IN-SCALAR): `IN (2019, 2020)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression you meant to write:

```
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR from start_date) IN (2019, 2020)
```

That is, `IN` expects a list within parentheses, not square brackets.

But I would actually suggest using explicit range comparison instead:

```
where start_date >= '2019-01-01'::date and start_date < '2021-01-01'::date
```

The advantage of this approach is that it is SARGeable, meaning it can take advantage of an index on column `start_date` (while the original expression needs to `extract()` the year from each and every row before being able to actually filter).